# Having trouble under Docker Compose getting OpenTelemetry trace information from my app into jaeger

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, jaeger, open-telemetry

I have a simple Node.js app the uses the Open Telemetry Jaeger exporter to send trace information into Jaeger. It runs fine when I fire up the Jaeger as a Docker container then run the code from my machine's command line against `localhost`. However, when I try to run both the app and jaeger under Docker Compose within a Docker Compose network, the service registers and is apparent in the Jaeger UI, but the trace/span information never gets received into Jaeger.

Here is the code: https://github.com/reselbob/simpletracing/tree/releases/v1.0

I attached a screenshot to demonstrate that the service seems to be registering but the spans are not getting through.

[image].

Comment: It's curious. I'm using `JAEGER_AGENT_PORT=6832` (not `6831`) and I observe similar behavior. However, if I choose "Compare" and plugin a couple of trace ID values, I'm able to observe the data in the Jaeger UI, can then see this listed under "Search", and can directly query an endpoint of the form: `http://localhost:16686/trace/${TRACE_ID}`. So, it appears (!) to be an issue with the Jaeger UI under the container.

Comment: I ran a Golang example and the HotRod example in the same Docker Compose 'network' and these both, correctly generate traces that are browsable from the Jaeger UI (without querying by trace). Interestingly, there are other API methods that are useful. `http://localhost:16686/services` lists known services (including `RandomWordGenUpper`) **but** if I query traces by service, I get zero results: `http://localhost:16686/api/traces?service=RandomWordGenUpper`. I've tried circumventing the agent and going directly but the behavior is consistent and I'm unable to browse traces using Node.

Comment: I added a [comment](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/1556#issuecomment-704547615) on your GitHub issue

Comment: Here is the fix that works. I got help from @naseemkullah on Gitter

https://github.com/reselbob/simpletracing/blob/releases/v1.0/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand what change that includes and it doesn't work for me. Was there an explanation given as to what we're doing wrong?

Comment: @DazWilkin, here you go: "get rid of JAEGER_SERVICE_NAME, JAEGER_AGENT_PORT and JAEGER_SAMPLER_MANAGER_HOST_PORT env vars, keep just JAEGER_AGENT_HOST, that worked for me after cloning your repo."